# How do I remove a select list option from a list generated from my Firebase DB?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Not sure I'm going about this correctly.  What I want to do is create a select list of options from my firebase db.  The list is returning and displaying as I expect.  I want to be able to select an option and click a "delete" button so I can delete options from the list.  Currently if I select an option all of the options disappear.  See [this page](http://www.threeinone.co.uk/#/categories) for an example.

What am I doing wrong?  Would I be better using ng-options here?

```
            <form name="categoryRemoveForm"  class="category-form">
                <select ng-model="cat">
                    <option ng-repeat="cat in cat.cats" value="{{cat.$id}}">{{cat.name}}</option>
                </select>  

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                           <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Remove Category" ng-submit="removeCategory(cat)" ng-disabled='!categoryRemoveForm.$valid'/>
                        </div>                            
                    </div>                      
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your model for select is named `cat` so when you select an option and set the model the `cat` in the `ngRepeat` is replaced by it due to inheritance so `cat.cats` is undefined and ngRepeat can not repeat it

here is the plunker demonstrating how your value changes

http://plnkr.co/edit/qLoe8j1QyZarNjHtaHT9?p=preview

So you should rename your model to something like `selectedCategory`, and as long as `removeCategory` is in the same scope you don't have to pass the model value